Show the value of IntegerRangeField next to the slider WTForms Python Flask
I have made a form which contains an IntegerRangeField and I want to have a number next to the slider which shows the value of the slider and updates it as it changes.
Form class
class ActivityQuantityForm(FlaskForm):
    activityQuantity = IntegerRangeField("quantity")
    submit = SubmitField()

HTML
`
{% if activity_quantity_form %}

<form method="POST" class="form-container">
    <div>
        <label for="quantity" class="roboto-light-500">Quantity</label>
        <div class="form-item">
            {{ activity_quantity_form.activityQuantity(class="form-input") }}
            {% for error in activity_quantity_form.activityQuantity.errors %}
                {{ error }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>{{ activity_quantity_form.activityQuantity.data }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% if fade_in == "activity_quantity_form" %}
        <div>
            {{ activity_quantity_form.submit(class="submit-button") }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</form>

{% endif %}

`

You can change element content using javascript. I tested this code on my computer, and it works well:
{% if activity_quantity_form %}
    <form method="POST" class="form-container">
        <div>
            <label for="quantity" class="roboto-light-500">Quantity</label>
            <div class="form-item">
                {{ activity_quantity_form.activityQuantity(class="form-input", oninput="changeRangeValue()") }}
                {% for error in activity_quantity_form.activityQuantity.errors %}
                    {{ error }}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div>
                <p class="range-value">50</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if fade_in == "activity_quantity_form" %}
            <div>
                {{ activity_quantity_form.submit(class="submit-button") }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </form>
{% endif %}

<script>
let range = document.querySelector('.form-input');
let rangeValue = document.querySelector('.range-value');

function changeRangeValue() {
    // get range value
    let val = range.value;

    // set this value in <p>
    rangeValue.innerHTML = val;
}
</script>

